# Copy a file with its parent dirs to a destination directory

Tags: files, rsync, cp

Source file : `~/SCRIPTS/script`

Destination directory : `~/TMP/LAB`

the command should be something like : `<command> <option> ~/SCRIPTS/script ~/TMP/LAB`

Desired result after the command : `~/TMP/LAB/SCRIPTS/script`

There's no point in doing

```
<command> <option> ~/SCRIPTS/script  ~/TMP/LAB/SCRIPTS/
```

Because I'll have to edit the command each time I change the source file. Basically I want the command to create the dirs based on the structure it finds in the source, not based on the target I desire to create.

The command should :

1. create ~/TMP/LAB/SCRIPTS/
2. copy ~/SCRIPTS/script to it.

`cp --parents` does that, but only when copying directories

I don't know if `install` can do that for me? or maybe `rsync` ?

Comment: `cp -r ~/SCRIPTS ~/TMP/LAB`?

Comment: @WhiteOwl that would copy everything inside ~/SCRIPTS/. It turns out I was wrong about `cp --parents`, it works when copying files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `cp --parents` if you have GNU `cp`.

```bash
bash-5.1$ tree
.
|-- SCRIPTS
|   |-- otherfile
|   `-- script
`-- TMP
    `-- LAB

3 directories, 2 files
```

```bash
bash-5.1$ cp --parents SCRIPTS/script TMP/LAB/
bash-5.1$ tree
.
|-- SCRIPTS
|   |-- otherfile
|   `-- script
`-- TMP
    `-- LAB
        `-- SCRIPTS
            `-- script

4 directories, 3 files
```

You suggested using `rsync`, which you can do if you use its `-R` (`--relative`) option:

```bash
bash-5.1$ rm -r TMP/LAB/SCRIPTS/
bash-5.1$ rsync -R SCRIPTS/script TMP/LAB/
bash-5.1$ tree
.
|-- SCRIPTS
|   |-- otherfile
|   `-- script
`-- TMP
    `-- LAB
        `-- SCRIPTS
            `-- script

4 directories, 3 files
```

Note that in both of these variations, using the absolute path `~/SCRIPTS/script` as the source rather than the relative path `SCRIPTS/script` would create directories corresponding to the absolute path at the destination, and you would end up with something like `TMP/LAB/home/myself/SCRIPTS/script`.

You would avoid this by first changing directories to the directory containing the `SCRIPTS` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the `rsync -R` tip, nice!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `cp --parents` create parents even when source is a file.